# In RoR, how do I send an https request over a socks port?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, https, socks, net-http

I’m using the below code to retrieve a web page through SOCKS

```
  uri = URI(url)
  content = nil
  status = nil
  content_type = nil
  res1 = Net::HTTP.SOCKSProxy('127.0.0.1', 50001).start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
    puts "launching #{uri.path}"
    resp = http.get(uri.path)
    status = resp.code
    content = resp.body
    content_type = resp['content-type']
  end
```

In advance, I don’t know if the url is going to be “http” or “https”.  When I try and connect to an https port, it appears the request is still sent over http as evidenced by below …

```
doc = WebpageHelper.get_url("https://whatismyip.com/")
```

which actually results in

```
2.3.0 :013 >   doc.to_s
 => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html>\r\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n<title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title>\n</head>\r\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>\r\n<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>\r\n<hr>\n<center>cloudflare-nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\n"
```

Is there something I need to set in the above that can force the request over https if it is actually an https web page?